# Null Pointer Exception on line 15,18 and 22

Tags: trigger, null-pointer, after-trigger

```
trigger RollUpSummaryTrigger on Contact(after insert) {

 Set < id > accIdList = new Set < id > ();
 for (Contact con: Trigger.new) {
  accIdList.add(con.accountid);
 }

 List < account > acList = [Select id, name,Rollup_Amount_X__c,Rollup_Amount_Y__c,Rollup_Amount__c, (Select Id, Type__c, Amount_X__c, Amount_Y__c From Contacts) From Account Where Id In: accIdList];
 if (acList != null && !acList.isEmpty()) {
  for (Account acc: acList) {
   if (acc.contacts != null && !acc.contacts.isEmpty()) {
    for (Contact con: acc.contacts) {
     if (String.isNotBlank(con.Type__c) && (con.Type__c == '+')) {

      acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c += con.Amount_X__c;
     } else if (String.isNotBlank(con.Type__c) && (con.Type__c == '-'))
     {
      acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c += con.Amount_Y__c;
     }
    }
   }
      acc.Rollup_Amount__c = acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c + acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c;
  }

 }
 update acList;
}
```

Getting this error on line no 15,18 and 22

Answer (score 3):

Best to have null guards on both parts of expressions like this:

```
acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c += con.Amount_X__c;
acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c += con.Amount_Y__c;
```

and one way to do that is to create a separate class that does null-guarded arithmetic:

```
acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c = GuardedMath.add(acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c, con.Amount_X__c);
acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c = GuardedMath.add(acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c, con.Amount_Y__c);
```

that looks something like this:

```
public class GuardedMath {

    public static Decimal add(Decimal a, Decimal b) {
        if (a != null && b != null) return a + b;
        else if (a != null) return a;
        else if (b != null) return b;
        else return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Check null in Account's Rollup_Amount_X__c & Contact's Amount_X__c.
Because there is impossible to add null to any other value. So please checkout null or else set it as 0 when it becomes null

```
if(acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c == Null) {

       acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c = 0;

   }

   if(con.Amount_X__c == Null) {

         con.Amount_X__c = 0;
   }
```

do remain as of you

```
acc.Rollup_Amount_X__c += con.Amount_X__c;

  } else if (String.isNotBlank(con.Type__c) && (con.Type__c == '-'))

   {

       acc.Rollup_Amount_Y__c += con.Amount_Y__c;

   }

}
```

Comment: Still the amount is not correctly calculated here

Comment: How to get the last task created time in salesforce